# Do I need to escape any characters for a json object?

Tags: javascript, json

In my code I am takign a class and converting it to JSON.

All my test is in double quotes, e.g.:

```
{ "a" : "hello world ! '' this is john's desk" }
```

Do I need to escape any characters when wrapped in double quotes?
Is it just double quotes inside of the string I need to escape?

Comment: depending on your use case. Normally for security reasons you would want to escape everything. Hope this helps!

Comment: Is this a manual conversion you're doing, or is it programmatic?  The easiest solution would be to use a library that will encode the value for you, for instance, `JSON.stringify()`.  At the very least you need to also escape backslashes.

Comment: The value of the property "a" of your object is a string.  So the question you are asking is "do I need to escape any characters to store them in a string" - no JSON here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can escape the quotes with `\"`.

Also, you can use `JSON.stringify()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify